# How to get details of error from .NET catch to React.JS?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

My Api Service is in .NET and my client side is in React.js. I use axios.post to send parameters and retrieve datas from .NET. I want to see error details on react.js side when something happened in service side. Example codes are below;

```
[HttpPost]
    public ConcreteAccrument CalculateDepositAmount([FromBody] DepositAmountParameters depositAmountParameters)
    {
        ConcreteApplication application = depositAmountParameters.application;
        int multiplier = depositAmountParameters.multiplier;
        bool forceCalculation = depositAmountParameters.forceCalculation;
        long registryInfoOid = depositAmountParameters.registryInfoOid;
        long subscriberRegistryOid = depositAmountParameters.subscriberRegistryOid;

        try
        {
            Com.BS.WaterSupplyAndSeverage.Services.WaterSupplyAndSewerage wssService = new Com.BS.WaterSupplyAndSeverage.Services.WaterSupplyAndSewerage();
            return wssService.CalculateDepositAmount(application, multiplier, forceCalculation, registryInfoOid, subscriberRegistryOid);
        }
        catch (BSException e)
        {
            FileLogger.Error(CLASS_NAME, "CalculateDepositAmount", e.Message, e.StackTrace, application, multiplier, forceCalculation);
            BSCommunicationException commException = new BSCommunicationException();
            commException.Id = e.Id;
            commException.ExceptionMessage = e.ExceptionMessage;
            throw new FaultException<BSCommunicationException>(commException, new FaultReason(commException.ExceptionMessage));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            FileLogger.Error(CLASS_NAME, "CalculateDepositAmount", e.Message, e.StackTrace, application, multiplier, forceCalculation);
            BSCommunicationException commException = PrepareCommunicationException(e);
            throw new FaultException<BSCommunicationException>(commException, new FaultReason(commException.ExceptionMessage));
        }
    }
```

There are some details in throw new FaultException at **first catch(BSException e)**. It's not a system error. For example,  data is null or some value are missing when **first catch** works. And second catch is system error. But in that code all catches return 500 error in React.Js side. All I want is to see all detail in first catch  on React.js side. When I use "return error" in catch then I get convert error because my class return an object.

Here my react.js code;

```
export const CalculateDepositAmount = (APPLICATION,MULTIPLIER,FORCE_CALCULATION,REGISTRY_INFO_OID, SUBSCRIBER_REGISTRY_OID, SuccessOperation, FailedOperation) => {
return () => {

const body = { application:APPLICATION,multiplier:MULTIPLIER,forceCalculation:FORCE_CALCULATION,registryInfoOid:REGISTRY_INFO_OID, subscriberRegistryOid:SUBSCRIBER_REGISTRY_OID};
console.log("bodyFormData",body)
axios.post('https://localhost:44396/api/CalculateDepositAmount', body)
  .then( async response => {
    SuccessOperation({ CALCULATED_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_DATA: await response.data });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    FailedOperation({ CALCULATED_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_DATA: null })
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Which dotnet version and which web-api version are you using?

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0 in my project and  I'm using ASP .NET Web Application for my  ApiController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that this is not asp.net core / 5 / 6, but vanilla 4.x

One thing you can do is change the method signature to `IHttpActionResult`, so you can return different status codes, with varying payloads back to the client:

```
public IHttpActionResult CalculateDepositAmount([FromBody] DepositAmountParameters depositAmountParameters) 
{
    try
    { 
       var result = wssService.CalculateDepositAmount(application, multiplier, forceCalculation, registryInfoOid, subscriberRegistryOid);
       return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (BSException e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message)
        //or
        //return StatusCode(418)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

You can tailor the response to the client much better to your needs, instead of return either the object or an exception. You can find the full list of here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn314678(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Another approach that will require some more refactoring, is to change the return type of your service to some sort of `Result` object, that indicates, whether it is a successfull operation or if a problem occured.

For example take this CommandResult example:

```
public class CommandResult<T>
{
    private CommandResult(T payload) => Payload = payload;

    private CommandResult(string failureReason)
    {
        FailureReason = failureReason;
    }

    public string FailureReason { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
    public bool IsSuccess => string.IsNullOrEmpty(FailureReason);

    public T Payload { get; }

    public static implicit operator bool(CommandResult<T> result) => result.IsSuccess;

    public static CommandResult<T> Success(T payload)
        => new(payload);

    public static CommandResult<T> Fail(string reason)
        => new(reason);
}
```

In your service you can now do the following:

```
public Commandresult<ConcreteAccrument> CalculateDepositAmount(DepositAmountParameters depositAmountParameters) 
{
    try
    { 
       var result = // do the calculation
       return CommandResult<ConcreteAccrument>.Success(result);
    }
    catch (BSException e)
    {
        return CommandResult<ConcreteAccrument>.Fail(e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return CommandResult<ConcreteAccrument>.Fail(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Now your controller simply has to decide, if it was successfull or not:

```
public IHttpActionResult CalculateDepositAmount([FromBody] DepositAmountParameters depositAmountParameters) 
{
    
   var result = wssService.CalculateDepositAmount(application, multiplier, forceCalculation, registryInfoOid, subscriberRegistryOid);
   if(result.IsSuccess)  // or simply if (result)
   {
       return Ok(result.Payload);
   }
   return Exception(result.FailureReason); //or whatever suits best.  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved my days. Your solution works well for my project.